# open62541 Client is disconnect from OPC-UA Server

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

first thanks to read this question

I have some problem about open62541 disconnect issue

I checked that the connection is lost every same cycle.

cycle time is 12min 40sec.

I checked connect status from this code

```
UA_ReadResponse response = UA_Client_Service_read(client, request);

if (response.responseHeader.serviceResult != UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
{
    return 0;
}
```

response.responseHeader.serviceResult isn't UA_STATUS_GOOD

response.responseHeader.serviceResult is UA_STATUS_GOOD before 12min 40sec

I added a temporary reconnection process and noticed that a message like the picture

below occurs every 12 min and 40 sec.

[image: Reconnect Picture]

And i check OPC-UA Sever

I used to B&R PLC.

The OPC-UA server role is played by B & R PLC and the settings are as shown below.

[image]

I suspect that I have nothing to do with setting up and disconnecting from B & R.

I want to find a solution or suspected part of this problem.

Please provide any additional information or estimates that may be needed for review.

Thanks

Comment: The console image only serves to show the results of the reconnection routine described above. The image at the top is neither an error message nor a code nor data. I have a question about whether the PLC configuration image at the bottom is a problem, and if I treat it as code I wonder if I must type these settings. I think it's the best way to communicate my status and it's hard to agree that it's against the rules of stackoverflow. If it's wrong, the image will be deleted.

Comment: users/162698/rob : Why do I drop my score and delete my comment and run away?
I'm amazed at your drowsiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem myself

I tested other open62541 version.

It is work. Just changed open62541

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing a similar issue with OPEN62541 version 1.1. How did you resolve the issue? which open62541 version you are using?

Comment: hello patel some open62541 code has error, i changed open62541 version, and working very well.